# Detect presence of text in image

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, image-classification

I want a simple image classifier to detect (No need to recognize) whether an image contains text or not. 
Some of the approaches I thought of:

1. Single class image classifier with a Threshold
2. Fast/Faster RNN technique

Which is the best approach?

And if I have to detect text or logo, is it efficient to use single class and feed all data together or use 2 classes?

Thank you